# gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://<bucket>/file.js Not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to use command `gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://<bucket>/file.js` to give read access to `file.js` It giving an error as `CommandException: AllUsers:R gs://<bucket>file.js is an invalid change description.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allUsers` not `AllUsers`:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/iam

So:

```
gsutil acl ch -u allUsers:R gs://<bucket>/file.js
```